# Using different ember adapters for different back end server requests

Tags: ember.js

I have two adapters `application.js` and `exam.js`. The `application.js` works as default adapter which will make requests to the url `http://localhost:8000/api/` In a different situation I need to make requests to the `http://localhost:8000/exam/` url. 
Suggest me a feasible method to do this

/adapters/application.js

```
import DRFAdapter from './drf';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DRFAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin,{
    authorizer: 'authorizer:custom',
    host: 'http"//localhost:8000',

    pathForType() {
        return '';
    }
});
```

/adapters/exam.js

```
import DRFAdapter from './drf';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DRFAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
    host: 'http://localhost:8000',
    namespace: 'exam',
    pathForType(){
        return 'e'
    }
});
```

/exam/controller.js

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({

    actions:{

        addExam: function(id){
            var examName = this.get('examname');
            let list = this.store.createRecord('exammodel',{
                name : examName,
                owner : id
            });
            list.save();
        },
    }

});
```

/exam/template.hbs

```
<form>
  {{input placeholder="exam name" type="text" value=examname required="required"}}
  <button type="submit" {{action "addExam" model.id}}>Add Exam</button>
</form>
```

when I type exam name and press submit, it shows an error in the console that **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)    `http://localhost:8000/api/`** which means we are still try to accessing the `localhost:8000/api/` but not `localhost:8000/exam/`

Comment: are you getting any errors? the approach you're using seems reasonable

Comment: I guess, could you go into more detail? is exam a model? or a whole namespace for a bunch of models?

Comment: these two calls(requests) are used to fetch data from different models in the backend

Comment: the `application.js`  is used to fetch data from user model and the other is to fetch from exam model

Comment: don't we have any way to use more than one adapters in ember?

Comment: yeah, what you're doing is almost correct, I'd get rid of the namespace in the exam adapter, as that would mean a query for the `exam` model is made to `/exam/e` (unless that's what you want).

Knowing what the backend api paths are for each model would be helpful, too :+1:

Comment: I think your question is why I used the namespace `/exam/e/` ? right?

Comment: perhaps? yeah?
Like, I'd also like to know what behavior you are seeing (like, what happens in the network tab of your browser), and how that is different from what you are expecting.
thanks!!! :)

Comment: because in the backend I have `exam model` and `questions model` in which `exam model` deals with the examination details such as exam_id, exam_name, etc... and `question model` deals with the questions that we can added to an exam model, it has a foreign key relation with the exam model

Comment: ok, I will give you those details soon

Comment: I have updated the question with the necessary details. please check it @NullVoxPopuli

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a slight naming mishap between the endpoint name and the model you're trying to create.

So, you have `/adapters/exam.js`, but are trying to `createRecord('exammodel'`

The adapter name needs to match the model name -- so the adapter will need to be  named `exammodel` or the call to cerateRecord should use ``` 'exam`` instead of ```'exammodel'`.

Hope this helps you progress! :)

Comment: it wasn't the right solution, there's something else wrong.

Comment: anyway I've removed the adapter and made the server request using Ajax command, Thanks for the support

Comment: why wasn't this the right solution? did you get any errors?

Comment: The problem is solved and the Error was while using a default adapter( application adapter) any other adapter calls will be replaced with this one